# how to restore the negotiation after changing the camera and microphone?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webrtc, simplewebrtc

About a month ago, a Stackoverflow partner helped me with a big question, like changing the camera and the microphone during a conference. That question was answered in the following link:

[Using WebRTC how to choose mic and camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54630591/using-webrtc-how-to-choose-mic-and-camera/54634812?noredirect=1#comment97519212_54634812)

After changing the camera and microphone, the previous media flow remains active. So the other people in the conference can not receive the new flow I have in some way.

I would like to know how to renegotiate this new flow, if necessary.

The library that I use for webRTC implementation in the project is "simplewebRTC" currently in disuse.

The code I use to change devices is based entirely on what was achieved in my previous question ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about simpleWebRTC, but in plain WebRTC renegotiation is not necessary.

Just use [sender.replaceTrack()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack). It's async, so to switch both camera and mic at the same time:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints) 
  .then(stream => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    return Promise.all(stream.getTracks().map(track => {
      const sender = pc.getSenders().find((s => s.track.kind == track.kind);
      return sender.replaceTrack(track);
    }));
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This should instantly cause the sender to switch to sending media from your new camera and microphone. The other side won't know the difference.